# Modifier Keyword order in Java

Tags: java, syntax, coding-style, access-modifiers

Every time I write a method in Java with more keywords than `public void`, every time I write it another way. Sometimes "`static public void`" sometimes "`public static void`" etc.

What is the best order (best practices) for these keywords?

[`abstract/static`] [`final`] [`synchronized`] [`public/private/protected`] [`result_type`]?

Comment: Sounds like a question of mine that got booted to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/... But personally I use `[public/private/protected] [final/abstract/static] [synchronized] [type] func()`...

Answer (score 79):

In theory it does not matter if you say public static final or final static public, but if you follow the usual convention, other people will able to read your code more easily. Here is the preferred order:

> [ public | protected | private ]
>
> static
>
> abstract
>
> synchronized
>
> [ transient | volatile ]
>
> final
>
> native
>
> strictfp
>
> [ int | long | String | class | enum | interface etc. ]

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub On provided JLS sections, It does not say anything about order restrictions, something like `It is compile time error, if you do not follow above order.` :)

Comment: I think the order for static and abstract are swapped according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3. Going to edit it..

Comment: @11thHourWorker: Considering that `static` and `abstract` cannot appear at the same time for one declaration their mutual order is irrelevant.

Comment: @Joey, `class Outer { static abstract class Inner {} }`

Answer (score 56):

[Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html) (which implements the suggestions of the Java Language Specifications sections, [8.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1), [8.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1), and [8.4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3)) says:

1. public
2. protected
3. private
4. abstract
5. default
6. static
7. final
8. transient
9. volatile
10. synchronized
11. native
12. strictfp

Comment: 1.-3. can never occur together so they should be tied to first place.

Comment: @KonradHöffner, No, it's much clearer this way.  Despite the technicality, I was hoping for a list where I could visually just pick and choose along a single dimension.  The fact that you cannot have, say, a `public protected` something is moot.  This is about overall ordering, _not_ about what's allowed together.  Sensible pairing is for the BNF (and the like) of languages, not this question.

Answer (score 9):

The custom usage order of the modifiers is mentioned in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/index.html)  (so no need to have an own opinion ;-)) e.g. for [method modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3) you will find the following definition (extract):

> ```
> MethodModifiers:
>     MethodModifier
>     MethodModifiers MethodModifier
>
> MethodModifier: one of
>     Annotation public protected private abstract
>     static final synchronized native strictfp
> ```
>
> If two or more (distinct) method modifiers appear in a method declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for MethodModifier.

You will find this sentence at several other places where the usage of modifiers is specified, e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1) for field modifiers.

(This is mostly copied from another answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16732059/367285)).

Answer (score 3):

The "best" would be to follow the [Java Coding Style Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20130425142804/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), that states in 6.2 (method declaration):

```
public static final synchronized long methodName()
    throws ArithmeticException, InterruptedException {
    static int count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best order is the one that the rest of your code uses.

Comment: Yes, but you can't deny that `public static final` is more common than `public final static`. There are some unwritten conventions.

Comment: Indeed, there are some pretty clear conventions in Javaland, for instance naming methods with infixCaps style. It is worth learning, and following them.

Comment: A lot of code is developed in teams. So, stick to the official convention.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

`public static final synchronized void calculate()`

Comment: `public static final synchronized void calculate()` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a standard ordering.

If you use an IDE, you can set it up to format your code for you, i.e. in Eclipse in Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions you can check the box "Format source code"

Then you don't have to worry about it any more. It will be done automatically whenever the file is saved and if your whole project uses this, then for the whole project has code that is formatted in the same way.

Comment: This does not re-order the modifiers AFAIK.
See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322494

Answer (score 0):

If you use SonarQube static analysis tool, or choose to follow its conventions, it should be:

1. public
2. protected
3. private
4. abstract
5. static
6. final
7. transient
8. volatile
9. synchronized
10. native
11. default
12. strictfp

See https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/convention/RSPEC-1124

Answer (score -1):

This is my personal choice

```
public static final void method() { }
public void method() { }
public abstract void method() { }
```

this seems in line too with the java documentation