# Placement of abstract keyword

Tags: java, syntax, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modifier Keyword order in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299067/modifier-keyword-order-in-java)

I am using netbeans IDE and i am checking out various  characteristics of JAVA .generally i declare a abstract class as follow

```
public abstract class ClassName
```

however the declaration  below doenot seem to generate any error either

```
abstract public class ClassName
```

What are the differences between the above two declarations?

Comment: the order of the modifiers is different..and no, that doesn't matter.

Comment: *I* always put the "visibility modifier" first. This is, however, *my* preference/convention.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference, but, I think `public abstract class ClassName` is more readable for most people.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference.  You can specify the qualifiers (public, abstract, etc.) in any order.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is the practice, I prefer to write/read it as

```
public abstract class ClassName {
```