# Order of defining types

Tags: c, types, coding-style

Is there any preference/convention/rule on order for defining a variable as `static` and `long/double` or other types?

e.g. is

```
static double a;
```

same as

```
double static a;
```

is it any different for functions? above, a is variable.

Comment: They mean the same thing.  The first version is overwhelmingly more common (in my experience).  But ultimately it's just a question of style.

Comment: Are the same, but `double static a` gives `warning: ‘static’ is not at beginning of declaration [-Wold-style-declaration]` with `-W` flag on

Comment: Nope. You just need to have the variable name last. Same with signed/unsigned, you can put them in any order. There was a question here earlier today or yesterday with a great response in it. Here 'tis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287957/is-long-unsigned-as-valid-as-unsigned-long-in-c

Comment: storage class should be first in declaration.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth see my answer, it's not only a question of style, the second form is marked as obsolescent.

Comment: @ouah: Did not know that, so +1 for you!

Comment: The close and downvotes here really aren't warranted.

Comment: It may be of interest, that some languages do define the preferred order. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299067/modifier-keyword-order-in-java

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are equivalent but `static` at the beginning is preferred.

> (C99, 6.11.5p1) "The placement of a storage-class specifier
>           other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a
>           declaration is an obsolescent feature"