# Method modifiers in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am writing code to match a method declaration given a string, or line. 
This is where my question came up. When trying to match the modifiers, I got stumped when the declaration

```
public static
```

worked. I have always done

```
static public
```

So here is my question. What is the difference between the two and is it the same for all modifiers. I'm sure there is a reason, and that the loose ordering is not a design decision.

Oh, and if one knows the best method for matching a method given a string, please tell me. Thanks. Right now I'm using regular expressions.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse method modifiers in .java files?

Comment: They're both valid because, why not?

Comment: C lets you do it. Apparently it's considered an "obsolescent feature." [Source](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) §6.11.15

Comment: @Shahar Yes I know there both valid but are they the same?

Comment: Yup they are the same.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Its part of a larger assignment

Comment: @agentNil For something serious, look into using either a library for interacting with bytecode (like BCEL) or an actual Java compiler (like the Eclipse Java Compiler). They've handled all the language quirks for you.

Comment: Note that the Java grammar is not regular and can't be parsed by regular expressions. It requires a recursive-descent or equivalent parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifier Keyword order in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299067/modifier-keyword-order-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same But as Generally we can write access modifier first then write Others modifiers.

Access modifiers:

- public
- private
- protected
- default (Package access)

Other modifiers for members of class :

- static
- final
- abstract
- synchronized
- native
- transient
- volatile

Method Syntax

```
<method modifiers> <return type> <method name> (<formal parameter list>) <throws clause> {
//method body
  <local variable declaration> 
  <inner class declaration>
  <statements>
}
```

Comment: So I guess then its just a matter of preference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is allowed and it is not loose ordering design but well defines grammar. For details you can check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) of grammar for Java language.

For example take class declaration -

```
ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration: 
    {Modifier} (ClassDeclaration | InterfaceDeclaration)
```

where

Modifier:

```
Annotation
public
protected
private
static 
abstract
final
native
synchronized
transient
volatile
strictfp
```

and

```
{x} denotes zero or more occurrences of x.
```

Comment: Additional explanation from [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3) in `8.4.3`:  "*If two or more (distinct) method modifiers appear in a method declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for MethodModifier.*".

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that as there is no actual point in enforcing such a rule, there isn't such a rule.

It is also easier in parsers to allow any order among several optional keywords than to require a specific order.